# inexact error in Julia -- matrix calculation

Tags: julia

The error happens after else condition. I want to replace A's column by new one. The following is the datatype of variables.It seems that it is datatype issue.

```
A = [1 1 1 1 1 0 0;
     1 2 0 3 0 1 0;
     2 1 2 0 0 0 -1;
     2 3 1 1 0 0 0]
b = [20 24 16 20]'
c = [-1 -2 -3 -4 0 0 0]'
C = [1 5 6 4]'

## convert the datatype of original data
C = vec(C)
# initial basis matrix
B = A[:, C]
# initial basic solution
x = inv(B)*b
c_B = c[C]
# initial reduced costs
c_r = (c' - c_B'*inv(B)*A)'
# if basic matrix is not identity (e.g., take other variables other than slack
# variables as starting point), convert B=I and N=inv(B)
ind = eye(length(C))
j = 1
if B != ind
    for i in length(c)
        if i in C
            A[:,i] = ind[:,j]
            j += 1
        else
            A[:,i] = inv(B)*A[:,i]
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: please edit your post and paste console text rather a screenshot image. The text will be formatted as code if preceded by four spaces. You can also use Ctrl+K for that

Comment: Note that `eye() has been deprecated in favor of I and Matrix constructors` in versions 0.7 and 1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following problems the code. First `A` is `Matrix{Int64}` and it should be `Matrix{Float64}`. You can fix it by writing:

```
A = Float64[1 1 1 1 1 0 0;
            1 2 0 3 0 1 0;
            2 1 2 0 0 0 -1;
            2 3 1 1 0 0 0]
```

Second - you probably want index `i` to range from `1` to `length(c)` so you should write your loop as:

```
for i in 1:length(c)
```

Finally - your code will not work under Julia 1.0 not only because `eye` is not defined, but also because you update variable `j` inside a loop. I would recommend you to wrap the whole code in a function or write `global j += 1` for it to work under Julia 1.0.

EDIT:

The problem - in a nutshell is the following:

```
julia> A = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> A[1] = 0.5
ERROR: InexactError: Int64(Int64, 0.5)
```

Array `A` can hold only integers, so you cannot assign a float to it. By writing `Float64` in front of array literal you force it to have another type of element, so this works:

```
julia> A = Float64[1,2,3]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0

julia> A[1] = 0.5
0.5

julia> A
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.5
 2.0
 3.0
```

In short Julia knows if your array holds integers or floats and checks it. Sometimes type promotion is allowed (e.g. you can assign an integer to an array of floats as this normally does not lead to the loss of precision) as is explained here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/conversion-and-promotion/#Conversion-1.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. The function eye works well in Julia on my laptop though I changes it to another. However the problem has been solved I still don't understand why it affects  A[:,i] = inv(B)*A[:,i].

Comment: I have added an explanation. I would highly recommend you to read the [Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/) as it contains many useful examples and explanations.